# Can the importance sampling estimator have a non-stationary behaviour policy even if the target policy is stationary?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, policies, off-policy-methods, importance-sampling

The *inverse propensity score* (IPS) estimator, which is used for off-policy evaluation in a contextual bandit problem, is well explained in the paper [Doubly Robust Policy Evaluation and Optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02834.pdf).

The old policy $\mu$, or the behavior policy, is okay to be non-stationary in the IPS estimator even if the new policy $\nu$, or the target policy, should be stationary.

Is this true for the *importance sampling* (IS) estimator, which seems to be a variant of IPS, for off-policy evaluation in a reinforcement learning problem?

IS estimator is explained in this paper [Doubly Robust Off-policy Value Evaluation for Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03722.pdf).

The target policy should be stationary, but can the old policy be non-stationary in the IS estimator?